# Specifying a domain for the z-axis in PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to draw a mesh in the domain { (x,y,z) in [0,4] }. I was able to constrain the domain in the x-axis and y-axis, but the mesh is still drawn in the negative z-axis (*Image 1*), which is outside the desired domain of [0:4]. I also tried the above with different plot types without success.

I was able to "hack" a solution by adding `restrict z to domain= 0:4` (*Image 2*) and completing the lattice with coordinates (*Image 3*).

**While I was able to hack together a solution, I am looking for a more elegant solution using only one `\addplot3`. Any suggestions are appreciated.**

Undesired result:
[image]
Source code for undesired result:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = center,   
                 y dir = reverse,
                 xmin=0, xmax=5, 
                 ymin=0, ymax=5, 
                 zmin=0, zmax=5] 
        \addplot3[mesh,
                  draw = black,
                  samples = 5,
                  domain = 0:4]
                  {4-x-y};
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result when adding `restrict z to domain= 0:4`:
[image]
Desired result (adding coordinates to complete the above lattice):

Added code: `\addplot3 [mark = none, draw = black]coordinates {(3,0,1) (4,0,0) (0,4,0) (0,3,1)};`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach with only one `addplot3`:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = center,   
   y dir = reverse,
   xmin=0, xmax=5, 
   ymin=0, ymax=5, 
   zmin=0, zmax=5,
   ] 
 \addplot3[
   patch,
   patch refines=4,
   mesh,
   draw = black,
   domain = 0:4,
   y domain = 0:4,
  ]
    table[z expr=4-x-y]
   {
    x  y
    0  0
    0  4
    4  0
   };
  \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could also plot it with the coordinates (at least for this simple example):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = center,   
   y dir = reverse,
   xmin=0, xmax=5, 
   ymin=0, ymax=5, 
   zmin=0, zmax=5,
   ] 
 \addplot3[
   patch,
   patch refines=4,
   mesh,
   draw = black,
   domain = 0:4,
   y domain = 0:4,
  ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0,4) (0,4,0) (4,0,0) 
    };
  \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```